# Why calling database dao function on UI?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am following kotlin android fundamental codelabs. There is a part where the app need a reference of all data from database

The following code is placed on ViewModel, database is passed as the instance of dao

```
val nights = database.getAllNights()
```

The implementation of getAllNights is as follows (In DAO)

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM daily_sleep_quality_table ORDER BY nightId DESC")
fun getAllNights(): LiveData<List<SleepNight>>
```

All other database calls are delegated to private suspend function and dispatched to IO thread except that one.

Isn't this call block the main thread

Why is it allowed

[CODELAB](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-coroutines-and-room/index.html?index=..%2F..android-kotlin-fundamentals#5)

Comment: probably because it returns live data, which _should_ be observed from the UI thread

Comment: There is another dao function that returns LiveData but it is not implemented that way @a_local_nobody